# Reset position of StringReader

Tags: xml, .net

```
 StringReader rdr = new StringReader(finalXML);

 //Reader is a property which returns XmlTextReader
 Reader = new XmlTextReader(rdr); 
 XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(rdr, settings);
```

The last line throws an exception as the root element is missing because it is at the end of the stream.
`_pos` value shows that it has read all the characters when I previously assigned it to the property in line 2.
Does any one know how to reset a StringReader?

Comment: Wow that's hard to understand.  Do you have a question?  If so, please don't conceal it as a comment in the code.

Comment: +1 for -1. Also, don't use XmlTextReader except for special purposes. This isn't one of them. Also, don't expose your Reader to callers. Comment out the "Reader =" line, and I bet the code works.

Comment: I have a requirement to use XmlTextReader and would not like to comment out that line. what I need is a way to reset the StringReader

Comment: +1 for -3 seems your post wasn't very well recieved.  sorry about that newbee

Comment: You don't want to "Rest" it - you want to not expose it, and you don't want to have two separate XmlReader instances using it. If you must expose it for some reason, then create a second StringReader.

Comment: @harry: Well, it was formatted so that the question could not be understood. Someone seeking help should at least put some effort in the question...

Comment: You want to review your requirement for XmlTextReader if it was created before .NET 2.0. Change "XmlTextReader" to "XmlReader". In any case, use a separate StringReeader. This isn't your last problem if you don't.

Comment: I know that you can use a second StringReader but want to avoid doing that

Comment: @chugh97 - *why* do you want to avoid using a second StringReader?

Comment: @Harry thanks... I think it makes sense now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially, you don't. Just create a new one... "reader"s are commonly one-way only. In some ways, having a settable "Reader" property that **consumes** the reader is confusing. Perhaps have a `Read(...)` or `Load(...)` method instead? It would be obvious that it has side effects then...

Answer (score 0):

As a best practice, you should use the static XmlReader.Create() method which uses the Factory Pattern rather than the constructor "new XmlTextReader(...)"